How can I conditionally return mutably borrowed data multiple times?
Given a function like this one, where values borrowed mutably from arguments could be returned from multiple locations, the borrow checker states that data is still mutably borrowed for the second call of get_mut, even though it is impossible for that mutable borrow to exist at that point.
fn func(data: &mut HashMap<String, u32>) -> Option<&mut u32> {
    if let Some(value) = data.get_mut("one") {
        return Some(value);
    }

    data.get_mut("two")
}

Is it there any way to get code with this behaviour to compile?

This is the classic issue polonius, the next borrow checker is set out to solve. For now you have to repeat the computation if data.get_mut("one").is_some() { return data.get_mut("one"); } … or use unsafe (preferrably through a crate that safely encapsulates it).
